# How to cancel or pause download operation of MKNetworkKit iOS?

Tags: ios, download, mknetworkkit

I am very new to iOS Programming and have been learning for only a month or two.
My plan is to download files from websites.
I am using MKNetworkKit and learning a little bit and testing it.
I can download the file from the web but I cannot pause or cancel the download.
I looked through the code but I don't know how to cancel the operation in the middle of the  download.
What I want to do is create a cancel button and when I hit it, it will trigger IBAction to cancel the download process.
Another step is pause the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pause a request. You can however cancel it and if your server supports Range headers, MKNetworkKit automatically resumes your download.

Comment: Mugunth, I'm not sure how to resume the download. I start a download with the addDownloadStream, then turn airplane mode on, get operationFailedWithError, then I start the same download again and instead of resuming it starts over. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your server support Range header? MKNetworkKit supports resuming only when your server sends Range headers