# how to resume downloads using MKNetworkKit in the event of network failure

Tags: objective-c, ios, mknetworkkit

MKNetworkKit allegedly supports resuming of interrupted downloads, but it's not clear how one would go about this. In another thread, it's developer says it works if the *server* sends Range headers.

[How to cancel or pause download operation of MKNetworkKit iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316414/how-to-cancel-or-pause-download-operation-of-mknetworkkit-ios)

However, it's my understanding that it is the *client* that sends Range headers. I would expect the library to see how much has been downloaded, and then request the appropriate range. I don't see any place in the code that does this.

The method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
```

does indeed check if a Range has been specified, but there seems to be no code actually doing the specifying.

Has anyone gotten MKNetworkKit to resume a download after network failure?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the freezable option, which as I understand doesn't work for GET, there isn't a way in the standard MKNetworkKit to resume a download. However, a slight modification does allow you to resume a download that has either been stopped by

beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

or by

operationFailedWithError

it requires saving downloadedDataSize to another property say resumeDownloadedDataSize and making this available to the calling object via a notification such as

```
NSDictionary *resumeDownloadedDataSizeDetails = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithLong:self.resumeDownloadedDataSize], @"resumeDownloadedDataSize", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMKNetworkOperationEndBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler object:self userInfo:resumeDownloadedDataSizeDetails];
```

(define kMKNetworkOperationEndBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in MkNetworkKit.h)

Set resumeDownloadedDataSize to 0 where the operation completes without error or interruption and make it equal to downloadDataSize when you want to resume.

Then add

```
if (self.resumeDownloadedDataSize !=0) {

            NSString* range = @"bytes=";
            range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithLong:self.resumeDownloadedDataSize] stringValue]];
            range = [range stringByAppendingString:@"-"];

            [[self request] setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
}
```

to

```
-(void) start
```

This code at the start of

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (self.downloadedDataSize == 0) {
        // This is the first batch of data
        // Check for a range header and make changes as neccesary
        NSString *rangeString = [[self request] valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
        if ([rangeString hasPrefix:@"bytes="] && [rangeString hasSuffix:@"-"]) {
            NSString *bytesText = [rangeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, [rangeString length] - 7)];
            self.startPosition = [bytesText integerValue];
            self.downloadedDataSize = self.startPosition;
        }
    }
```

Now works for my added offset as the client has requested a range.

I also added

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger resumeDownloadedDataSize;
```

to the header file so I could set it from other views.

Now in your calling object you can listen for the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didMKNetworkOperationEndBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) name:kMKNetworkOperationEndBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler object:nil];
```

check it's for you and restart the operation setting a range.

```
- (void) didMKNetworkOperationEndBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    if ([[notification object] isEqual:downloadOperation]) {
        resumeDownloadedDataSize = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"resumeDownloadedDataSize"];
        bDownloadOperationCancelled=YES;
    }
}
```

As I am using this for a large file download, the expiration handler expires and I restart the operation when I come back into foreground.

```
if (bDownloadOperationCancelled) {
        NSLogDebug(@"DownloadOperationCancelled restarted");
        [self doFileDownload];
        bDownloadOperationCancelled=NO;
}
```

where

```
- (void) doFileDownload
{
    downloadOperation = [ApplicationDelegate.downloadEngine downloadVideoFile:authDownloadURLString toFile:downloadPath withOffset:resumeDownloadedDataSize];
(Your code for handling completion blocks etc)
…

}
```

The final piece is to make sure in your engine you set append to YES

```
[op addDownloadStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:YES]];
```

So a resume adds to the file.

Just to also be clear I am using AWS CloudFront and this supports the use of range headers when data is stored in S3.

This appears to work for me. I am sure there are more elegant ways of doing it.

Comment: Just updating my own answer. I subsequently found this [post](http://nachbaur.com/blog/resuming-large-downloads-with-nsurlconnection) that shows how to check that the server can honour the HTTP-Range header.